# Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component (React Native, Expo, React Hooks)

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, expo, warnings, use-state

In react-native app, I'm getting this error:

`Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in %s.%s, a useEffect cleanup function`

I've seen a few posts similar to this problem but I'm having problems making them connect to my problem.

The app is not broken, it's just getting this nasty warning that I would really like to fix. The warning mentioned using a useEffect cleanup function, but I wasn't even using useEffect in the component at the time, so I decided to add one, but it didn't help.

```
  useEffect( () => {

    if (action) {

      let controller = new AbortController();

      const loadData = async () => {
        try {
          const response = await fetch( action, { signal: controller.signal } );
          const data = await response.json();

          if ( data ) {
            setIdKey( data );
            setIsValid( true );
            setLoggedIn( true )
            setBadCreds( false );
            setAuthenticating( false );
            setHasLoggedIn( true );
            console.log('has logged in: ' + hasLoggedIn);
          } else {
            setContainerHeight( 20 );
            setBadCreds( true );
            setIsValid( true );
            setAuthenticating( false );
          }
        }
        catch ( error ) {
          setAuthenticating( false );
          if ( error.name == 'AbortError' ) {
            console.log( 'FetchCancel: caught cancel' );
          } else {
            console.log( error.message );
            throw error;
          }
        }
      };

      loadData();

      return () => {
        console.log( 'FetchCancel: unmounting' );
        controller.abort();
      }
    }

  }, [action] );
```

I'm using react hooks throughout and don't have any experience with the older methods.

The error is technically reporting this from the parent component.

Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Comment: This seems duplicated with another question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56442582/react-hooks-cant-perform-a-react-state-update-on-an-unmounted-component

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59780268/cleanup-memory-leaks-on-an-unmounted-component-in-react-hooks?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I've done my best to apply the options from those questions and nothing has changed. This is not the solution to my problem.